# Is there an equivalent for French "CQFD"

Tags: translation, acronyms, phrase-requests, french

In French, when concluding a demonstration, we say "CQFD", which stands for "Ce Qu'il Fallait Démontrer" (What was to be demonstrated).

Does English have an equivalent for this ?

Comment: "This concludes the demonstration" is about it for a demonstration. Unless you're talking about mathematics, when you have proven a theorem. At the end of a proof, one may place "QED" from _Quod Erat Demonstrandum_ 'That which was to be demonstrated'. Outside the "D" in _Demonstrandum_, however, _Demonstration_ is not normally used in its mathematicological sense in English, outside a specificially logical or mathematical context. Which is not summoned up by use of the phrase "concluding a demonstration".

Comment: A completely language agnostic option would be to use ∎ (the tombstone mark). This is most commonly seen at the [end of a proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.#Electronic_forms).

Comment: CQFD in French is Ce Qu'il Faut Démontrer, placed at the end of a mathematical demonstration.
But sometimes, we the french mean by CQFD : Ce Qu'il Fallait Dire = what had to be said.

Comment: In common language, CQFD signifies to your interlocutor that (s)he has perfectly illustrated your point and that you are in complete agreement.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Q.E.D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D) - Quod erat demonstrandum - is put at the end of of a proof to signify that what we attempted to prove has been proven.

[Q.E.F.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D#QEF) - Quod erat faciendum - is a term that is used in geometric proof to signify that the geometric construction has been completed. It is a rarely used English abbreviation.

From the article the correct translation is Q.E.F. but from your description Q.E.D. sounds more accurate because it comes at the end of a proof/demonstration.

Note: From the comments below CQFD is always equivalent to QED.